# Node.js location of uploaded file

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, file-upload

I'm very new of Node.js. I am trying to implement a online file converting service, but I have trouble knowing where should I store the converted file. Because I don't want anyone but the user can access that file. Is the folder "public" a right choice to store the file? Thanks.

Here is my structure.

```
WebApp
├── bin
├── node_modules
│   ├── body-parser
│   ├── cookie-parser
│   ├── debug
│   ├── express
│   ├── jade
│   ├── morgan
│   ├── multer
│   ├── node-uuid
│   ├── remove
│   ├── serve-favicon
│   ├── sqlite3
│   └── stripe
├── public
│   ├── bower_components
│   ├── converted
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   ├── previews
│   ├── stylesheets
│   └── uploads
├── routes
├── ssl
└── views
    └── partials
```

Comment: Could you please share your folder structure?

Comment: @GökayGürcan, I've added my folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serving private files from such `public` folder (it looks like your `public` folder is a place static files are served from) is not good idea - anyone who has the link can download it.

You should create a custom download route handler instead, which is responsible for verifying that it is really the owner who is trying to download particular file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a standard generated Express app.

Absolutely do not store in the public directory, its open access for anyone.

You have multer in your packages, so I'm assuming you have your file upload modules already. Now just use some sort of middleware authentication package, like PassportJs, and use that to authenticate in a routing file or a controller file.